# Как отменить удаление Default Web Site в IIS

Tags: iis

Собственно, удалил Default Web sSite в IIS. Помогите восстановить, или же проще создать новый? Если лучше создать новый, то подскажите как корректно это сделать. Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Вопрос можно удалить

Comment: если у вас есть решение заданного вопроса, пожалуйста, изложите это решение, ответив на свой вопрос. здесь это нормально и даже приветствуется.

Comment: Закрыть как "проблема, которая больше не воспроизводится"? Да я сам default web site удалял пару раз, воспроизводится на ура.

Comment: @PashaPash А как ещё реагировать на фразу _"Вопрос можно удалить"_, озвученную автором вопроса?

Comment: @Regent если нет уверенности, что это действительно невоспроизводимая проблема или опечатка - оставить открытым. У автора есть кнопка "удалить". если хочет - пусть нажимает.

Comment: @PashaPash у меня есть подозрение, что незарегистрированные пользователи не могут удалять свои вопросы. Но даже если и могут, то далеко не все удосуживаются это сделать в случае необходимости. По крайней мере, в данном случае автор отписался, и его мнение нам известно. Если рассчитывать на полезность вопроса и ответа для будущих пользователей, то вопрос стоит доработать.

Answer (score 2):

Есть два способа откатить удаление:

#### Поднять их автоматического бэкапа

IIS сохраняет историю конфигурации, на всякий случай.

- найти в C:\inetpub\history папку с конфигом, в котором еще упоминается Default Web Site
- скопировать ее содержимое в C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config
- перезапустить IIS

#### Переустановить IIS и WAS:

Это откатит конфиг на стандартный.

- открыть Add remove programs"
- выбрать Turn windows features on or off
- удалить IIS and WAS (Windows Process Activation Service)
- перезагрузить машину
- открыть Add remove programs"
- выбрать Turn windows features on or off
- установить IIS and WAS (Windows Process Activation Service)